# how i can get the each sms id in android

Tags: android

actually i want to delete sms  from inbox as per id i am using following code

but it showing error

my code:

```
Uri deleteUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");
Cursor m_cCursor=context.getContentResolver().query(deleteUri, null, null,    null, null);
int m_cnum=m_cCursor.getCount();
int id =m_cCursor.getInt(0);
int thread_id = m_cCursor.getInt(1);
```

the error is:

```
 0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 21]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.content.ContextWrapper
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: name index: 1 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: mode index: 2 type: int
```

Comment: The SMS content provider is not part of the public SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do `m_cCursor.moveToFirst()` and `m_cCursor.moveToNext()`?

Answer (score 0):

After

```
 Cursor m_cCursor=context.getContentResolver().query(deleteUri, null, null,    null, null);
```

add

```
     while (cur.moveToNext()) {
         int m_cnum=m_cCursor.getCount();
         int id =m_cCursor.getInt(0);
         int thread_id = m_cCursor.getInt(1);
    }
```